# Multiple cursors from find result

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have a regex in my find box and want a cursor at each found location (I'm actually trying to delete a load of new lines in paragraphs but there's far to many to do by hand).

How can I get a cursor at each location that matches `[\w]$`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Click the "Find All" button at the far right of the find panel, and ST will select all the matches.
[image: search box with find all circled]

Comment: I'd literally just figured out it was that simple.  I thought that would give me the same result as _find in files_.  I'll mark you up in 9 minutes!

Answer (score 5):

The shortcut `Opt + Enter` should work if you're looking to stay on the keyboard.

Comment: As described, Cmd+F for word, then Opt+Enter

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search for a simple string, you may select it right in editor and use Find All:

Windows/Linux: Alt+F3

Mac: ⌃+⌘+G